# Transferring decrypted data from CryptoStream to SecureString

Tags: .net

I am attempting to transfer decrypted data into a System.Security.SecureString from a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream. Looking at the IL code for CryptoStream, it appears to buffer the transformed data like any other System.Buffer. I could read out the data in large chunks and then append it to my SecureString; the buffered data is short lived (within the method) but the SecureString itself may hang around for awhile.

Does it make any sense to pin the buffered data in memory with GCHandle to reduce the attack surface by preventing copies by the GC, or is this totally not needed? Also, is there a better way to put the transformed data from the CryptoStream into a SecureString?

Comment: did you get any success in this ?!

Comment: @Ali In my case, the security gained was not really worth the extra code complexity, especially considering the asset being secured. If you feel that the exploit risk and asset value is high, it definitely couldn't hurt to do this.

Unfortunately there is not a very good blanket answer. The size of the buffer, memory changes by other threads and the allocation threshold of the generation 0 collection can all determine whether compaction and a copy will occur in the managed heap.